# Android Studio: Trouble connecting Huawei device to Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, driver, huawei-mobile-services

I'm new to Android Studio and at the moment i'm trying to run my Android Studio apps on my device (HUAWEI P20 PRO) but nothing works for me. Android Studio doesn't show my device in AVD manager.

Can you tell me what I've missed?

- USB debugging is on
- Driver is installed with HiSuite (in device manager: Huawei HDB Interface) 
  Note: Google USB Driver is installed through Android Studio.

Using Android Studio 3.5

Comment: Hi, I have this issue too. Are you able to fix it ?

Comment: Yeah, what worked for me was to make sure that i clicked "Transfer files" on the phone when it was plugged in to the PC. Then I toggled OFF USB debugging and then ON again. Suddenly, my device showed up as an option in "Available devices".

Comment: Is your USB mode set to Charge? I have a P10 Lite and the only way I can do apps over the USB cable is via charge.

Comment: Mine only works when I set the USB mode to 'Transfer files'.

Comment: I also solved setting debug-mode on and 'Trasfer files' on usb

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved: 
What worked for me was to make sure that I clicked "Transfer files" on the phone when it was plugged in to the PC. Then I toggled OFF USB debugging and then ON again. 
Suddenly, my device showed up as an option in "Available devices" in Android Studios.

Comment: this works 2023

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution in the [chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61840662/1348839) I had to restart android studios for my device to appear in available devices.